# my game crashes when i have too many threads running and i dont know why

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, pygame

i didnt involved my settings here because thats just basic information and stuff my problem in this code is at the threading. the game just lagges extremly when i involve my threads T4 and T5 and i dont know why because i thought threads are like an side code with no efFect on the main code . hope you can help me here thanks!

```
from settings import *

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption('Space shoter!')  
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def draw_score(surf, text, size, x, y):

def checkscore(): 

bossinvinc = False
def draw_healthbar(surf, x, y, pct,maxhp):

def playermovement():

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

class Mob(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

class Laser(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

class Spawnmeteroits(Thread):
    def run(*args):
        global spawnthebig
        while running:
            if meterorfallactv:
                for _ in range(random.randint(2, 4)):
                    m = Mob(tinymeteroit, tinyspeed , tinyHP, tinypoints)
                    mobs.add(m)
                    all_sprites.add(m)
                time.sleep(1)
                if spawnthebig:
                    spawnthebig = False
                    m = Mob(bigmeteroit, bigspeed , bigHP, bigpoints)
                    mobs.add(m)
                    all_sprites.add(m)
                time.sleep(1)


class Spawnmeteroitsmedium(Thread):
    def run(*args):
        while running:
            if meterorfallactv:
                time.sleep(3)
                for _ in range(random.randint(1, 2)):
                    m = Mob(mediummeteroit, mediumspeed , mediumHP, mediumpoints)
                    mobs.add(m)
                    all_sprites.add(m)

class Shotlaser(Thread):
    def run(*args):
        while running:
            pulscannonXleft = shipcenter - 23
            pulscannonXright = shipcenter + 14
            pulscannonY = shipbottom - 52
            Lleft = Laser(pulscannonXleft,pulscannonY)
            Lright = Laser(pulscannonXright,pulscannonY)
            lasershotsR.add(Lright)
            lasershotsL.add(Lleft)
            all_sprites.add(Lleft,Lright)
            time.sleep(attackspeed)
```

**heres one of these threads**

```
bossfightstart = False
lethtebosscome = False
class Bossfight(Thread):
    def run(*args):
        global bossfightstart, lethtebosscome, bossinvinc
        while running:
            if lethtebosscome:
                print('yeye')
                bossinvinc = True
                boss = Endboss(bosshealth)
                all_sprites.add(boss)
                stagebossfight.add(boss)
                while boss.rect.x > 70:
                    pass
                lethtebosscome = False
                bossfightstart = True
                bossinvinc = False



Laserabilityoff = False
class Boss_laser(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = laserstart
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = random.randint(150, 600)
        self.mask = pygame.sprite.from_surface(self.image)
        if self.rect.centerx <= 170:
            self.rect.centery = 170
        else:
            self.rect.centery = 190
    def update(self):
        self.rect.y += 10
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.mask = pygame.sprite.from_surface(self.image)
        if self.rect.top > HEIGHT:
            self.kill()
        if Laserabilityoff:
            self.kill()
```

**heres one of these threads**

```
class firebosslaser(Thread):
    def run(*args):
        while running:
            if bossfightstart:
                global Laserabilityoff
                time.sleep(random.randint(4, 7))
                for _ in range(random.randint(3, 6)):
                    BL = Boss_laser()
                    all_sprites.add(BL)
                    stagebossfight.add(BL)
                time.sleep(3.5)  # durating of existence
                Laserabilityoff = True

def playergetshit():
    global Playerhealth
    meterorhits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player,mobs,False) 
    if  meterorhits:
        truemeterorhits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player,mobs,True,pygame.sprite.collide_mask)
        for _ in truemeterorhits:
            player.HP -= 1
            Playerhealth -= 1

def meteroitsgethit():
    LaserhitsR = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(mobs, lasershotsR, False, False)
    if LaserhitsR:
        truelaserhitsR = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(mobs, lasershotsR, False, True,pygame.sprite.collide_mask)
        for hit in truelaserhitsR:
            hit.health -= LaserDMG
    LaserhitsL = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(mobs, lasershotsL, False, False)
    if LaserhitsL:
        truelaserhitsL = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(mobs, lasershotsL, False, True,pygame.sprite.collide_mask)
        for hit in truelaserhitsL:
            hit.health -= LaserDMG


class Endboss(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,bosshp):
        global meterorspeed
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = finalboss
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.HP = bosshp
        self.rect.y = 0
        self.rect.x = 810
        self.mask = pygame.sprite.Sprite(self.image)
        meterorspeed = 0

    def update(self):
        # movement to middle of the screen noch invincible
        if self.rect.x > 70:
            self.rect.x -= 3.5
        self.mask = pygame.sprite.from_surface(self.image)




player = Player(Playerhealth)
healthbarX = player.rect.x - 18
healthbarY = player.rect.y + 69
all_sprites.add(player)



# game loop
running = True
meterorfallactv = True
# thread start
T1 = Spawnmeteroits(daemon = True)
T1.start()
T2 = Shotlaser(daemon = True)
T2.start()
T3 = Spawnmeteroitsmedium(daemon = True)
T3.start()
T4 = Bossfight(daemon = True)
T4.start()
T5 = firebosslaser(daemon = True)
T5.start()


while running:
    clock.tick(fps)
    screen.fill((40, 40, 40))
    screen.blit(background,background_rect)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        playermovement()
    all_sprites.update()
    playergetshit()
    meteroitsgethit()
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    draw_healthbar(screen, healthbarX, healthbarY, Playerhealth,PlayerMaxHealth) 
    checkscore()
    pygame.display.flip() 
pygame.quit()
```

i had to disable some of my code because im not allowed to post this much code but its not important the problem is with the threads

Answer (score 0):

In Bossfight, you have this:

```
                while boss.rect.x > 70:
                    pass
```

That's a "busy loop"; the interpreter will basically stop there, but will continuously check `boss.rect.x > 70`. Replace `pass` with a short sleep to keep it from eating too much CPU.

firebosslaser has a similar problem: If `bossfightstart` is False, it will loop forever. Add `else: time.sleep(5)` after that loop and you should be OK.